# cannot add spigot to build path succesfully for 1.18 plugins

Tags: java, import, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I've been trying to import spigot/bukkit for minecraft plugins. When trying to create the main class, I entered

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

}
```

With an error under JavaPlugin, since their is no import. The tutorial im following told me to click the fix that will import it for me, but
the fix simply does not show up when I attempt to resolve it, and if I manually import it, it gives the error: "the import org.bukkit.plugin cannot be resolved." I've tried restarting the project, deleting and reinstalling, and everything in between. Please let me know if you need more information on how I've added spigot to the build path, or anything else I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 1.17, it seems to have some changes with jar. Now, if you start server, it will create the `bundler/versions` folder, with a given jar that -for me- should fix your issue.

Also, you can use more preferable way to import project, such as [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/). They can help you to easier share the project, and make it faster to run (you can also automatically run it with github actions for example.

- To use spigot with **maven**, use this:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
           <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

([Documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-maven/))

- To use spigot with **gradle**, use this:

```
repositories {
  maven { url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
  maven { url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central' }
}

dependencies {
  compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

([Documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-gradle/))

Comment: awesome, thank you! I'll give this a try tonight and report back to you.

Comment: @Drand did it answer, and if yes can you upvote/accept the answer ?